# options "--read-only" Ipython Notebook

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

I can't run my ipython notebook with the --read-only option.
It says :

```
[NotebookApp] CRITICAL | Unrecognized flag: '--read-only'
```

It's weird because I've seen several blog mentionning it.
I'm running with the 1.1 version of ipython.

Do you know if this option was removed or moved elsewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes the option was removed, it might be re-introduced in another form later when nbconvert/nbviewer is refined, but you better run your own local instance of nbviewer to this effect.

Comment: Thanks! Is it plan for the version 2.0?

Comment: Thats bad. Is there any other flag/option to reach the same effect as the `--read-only` flag?

Comment: nbviewer can be installed locally and has option to serve files from disk.

Comment: It is +3 years after this answer and  `--read-only` seems not to have been reintroduced. Should it be edited to say that it is gone for good?

Comment: Likely. Done.  THanks.

Answer (score 9):

There is a super easy way to do what you're trying to do I think though--simply use OS security.

Do this:

1. When you're ready to deploy to read only, make a special folder
   for your read-only work, and copy your *.ipynb files into that.
2. Make the *.ipynb files read-only at the Linux level: chmod 444
   *.ipynb.
3. Run iPython Notebook from that directory.  Use a different port
   so that it won't conflict.
4. Send the URL to everyone using the URL that has the read-only
   port.
5. They can then read it all, even run code, but they will not be
   able to save changes.
6. They cannot navigate anywhere outside that directory.  E.g. the
   little home icon only brings them to the folder with your read-only
   content.
7. Thus they have full access to the page and its functionality, but
   cannot mess it up on anyone else.  And all you need is a cp and a
   chmod.  Profit!

At least this solved my need.  I have my regular port with write authority for all my development, then I copy it over, chmod it, and let people at it.  Works just fine for me.

Hope this helps others!

Comment: I haven't tried this, but can they add new cells (event without saving)? If this is the case, you  should run it as an other user, to avoid somebody experimenting with command line on the system

Comment: Less convenient that a --read-only option at server startup, but effective.

Comment: _They cannot navigate anywhere outside that directory_   that is not correct, they can still do things like `ls ~` or `less ~/.vimrc` or similar things